# Ids in an included XML layout for a table

Tags: android, xml

How should I implement a table of 15 by 15 cells if I plan to dynamically update the cells individually?

I began creating the table in my main.xml, but I don't want to describe the table with 15 TableRow elements and 15 elements in each of those all in one body of code. I feel like even putting just the table itself in a separate file is too bulky. It is possible to create a file of a row and and a file of a table including the row 15 times and dynamically assign different IDs to each cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do comething like:

```
public void generateTable() {
    TableLayout tv = new TableLayout(context);

    for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
        for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(context);
            tr.addView(tv);
            tv.setText("ID: " + (y*15 + x));
            tv.setId(y*15 + x);
            // And to allow for easy reading
            if (y*15+x % 2 == 0)
                tv.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
            else
                tv.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000ff);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the generally accepted guidelines for when to use a layout and when to build it programmatically?

Comment: There aren't any really. Just try to make it clean.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table layout like this from xml

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_table);
```

You can create a table row in xml as tablerow.xml.This will help you to define table row layout in an easier way.I am adding only 1 TextView.

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:id="@+id/content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    />
```

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    for (int rowID = 0; rowID < 15; rowID++) {
      TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.id.tablerow, tl, false);
      TextView content = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.content);
      content.setId(rowID); 
      content.setText("this is the content"); 
      tl.addView(row);
    }
```